# Implementing a model with two separate attributes with different names but with same type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations, rails-models

I have a Model named `Lock` which keeps track of two `Students` who have locked a deal with each other. My `Lock` model has attributes `buyer_id` and `seller_id` which both are the `id`'s of `users` from my `User` model. Is there a way to have attributes `buyer` and `seller` (for `Lock` model) that directly access their appropriate `User`?

For example, I would like to make a call like `Lock.last.buyer.email` instead of having to go through the `user_id` like `User.find(Lock.last.buyer_id).email`.

Also, will this difference in syntax make for better code? Or am I merely making a syntactical improvement for my own readability? Either way, I would like to know if its possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these

```
belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :buyer_id
belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :seller_id
```

There is more info about `belongs_to` in [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to).

Comment: What should the migration be in this case?

Comment: ```add_column :locks, :buyer_id, :integer``` And if you are going to use the reverse relationship, you should add an index too. ```add_index :locks, :buyer_id```. Same for ```seller_id```.